# Unable to access get function of model in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to access property of model in angular. However, it always returns null. In my component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.countryService.getCountries(10, 1).subscribe(res => {
      var obj = res as Listresponse;
      console.log(obj.getTotalRecords);
    })
  }
```

Service gets data like this:

```
getCountries(pageSize: number, pageIndex: number) : Observable<Listresponse>  {
    let request = {
      "pageSize": pageSize,
      "pageIndex": pageIndex
    };
    return this.http.post<Listresponse>('https://localhost:44337/api/Country/List', request);
  }
```

Model is like below:

```
export class Listresponse {
    private result: boolean;
    private resultdesc?: string;
    private totalRecords: number;
    private records: Array<any>;


    constructor($result: boolean, $resultdesc: string, $totalRecords: number, $records: Array<any>) {
        this.result = $result;
        this.resultdesc = $resultdesc;
        this.totalRecords = $totalRecords;
        this.records = $records;
    }

    getRecords(): Array<any> {
        return this.records;
    }

    getTotalRecords(): number {
        return this.totalRecords;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is ListResponse instantiated? Angular does not magically instantiate the class because of the post<ListReponse>, that is simply a generic telling it which interface you are expecting it to return.

Answer (score 0):

`http` returns object. Not a class instance. You have to modify as below.

```
export interface Listresponse { // not class, but interface
    result: boolean;
    private resultdesc?: string;
    private totalRecords: number;
    private records: Array<any>;
}
```

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.countryService.getCountries(10, 1).subscribe(res => {
      var obj = res as Listresponse;
      console.log(obj.totalRecords);  // not getTotalRecords
    })
  }
```